# Can't move camera in A-Frame with Oculus Quest 2

Tags: aframe, oculus, webxr, oculusquest

Is it possible to move camera in A-Frame projects with Oculus touch controllers?

Can't find any working example.

Comment: If you share complete simple code illustrating your attempt and it will be much easier to help you. glitch.com/~aframe is great for people to run it and suggest solutions. Best of luck! To animate your camera in VR you will have to wrap it in a rig as described in the examples you can then move the rig: https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/camera.html#examples

Comment: You can listen to events coming from the controllers and manipulate the rig accordingly: https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/oculus-touch-controls.html#sidebar

Comment: Tried to describe re-using `wasd-controls`, ended up making a "component" x)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try and re-use existing components. [wasd-controls](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/wasd-controls.html#sidebar) are working well for movement, so You can write a similar component utilizing the [thumbstick input](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/components/oculus-touch-controls.html#read-thumbstick-values) instead of the `wasd` keys.

---

You can try out my barbaric attempt [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/controls/oculus-thumbstick-controls.html)([docs](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/blob/master/aframe/controls/README.md)).
It's quite simple - create a **rig** for the controllers + camera and attach **oculus-thumbstick-controls** to any controller:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/controls/oculus-thumbstick-controls.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <!-- Camera + controllers rig -->
  <a-entity id="rig">
    <a-camera position="0 1.6 0"></a-camera>
    <a-entity oculus-touch-controls="hand: left" ></a-entity>
    <a-entity oculus-touch-controls="hand: right" oculus-thumbstick-controls></a-entity>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: That is amazing and simple, I've been trying to find out how to do this for days now. Shame this example isn't given in the a-frame documentation.